# installation error for ROracle in pkgdown workflow

Tags: github, workflow, action, roracle

In developing an R package i have `ROracle` as a dependency.

I have a github workflow (usethis::use_github_pages()) that creates a pkgdown website for the R package

The workflow [fails](https://github.com/andybeet/dbutils/actions/runs/5869304717/job/15914007300#step:5:2527) trying to install `ROracle` and i dont understand why.

I have not seen this before, and i have created many R packages. I am guessing it may be related to a system setting but unsure as to what since the documentation is insufficient